# Align Geometry to Plane selecting 3 intersected points

Tags: math, three.js, quaternions

I have a few days trying to align the 3D object selecting 3 points intersected on the 3D object.

I have to align the GEOMETRY to the the plane.

I started getting the crossVectors from the 3 points.

First Step i did is to move the first point selected to the 0,0,0 position:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

After move, as you can see the points are not updated.

```
let matrixToApply = new Matrix4().makeTranslation(
            -this.aligningPoints[0].x, 
            -this.aligningPoints[0].y, 
            -this.aligningPoints[0].z
        );
 this.mesh.geometry.applyMatrix4(matrixToApply)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

After this step, the next is to rotate the first point and the second one, getting the angle between, it's so stupid code, I need some help to get some better solution for tha, like apply quarention on euler. I just need to rotate and match to the plane.

```
if (crossVectors.x > 0 && crossVectors.y > 0 && crossVectors.z < 0) {

            console.log('+ + -');

            var rotateX = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 100).angleTo(new THREE.Vector3(0, crossVectors.y, crossVectors.z));

            this.mesh.geometry.rotateX(rotateX);

        } else if (crossVectors.x > 0 && crossVectors.y < 0 && crossVectors.z < 0) {

            console.log('+ - -');

            var rotateX = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -100).angleTo(new THREE.Vector3(0, crossVectors.y, crossVectors.z));

            this.mesh.geometry.rotateX(rotateX);

        } else if (crossVectors.x > 0 && crossVectors.y < 0 && crossVectors.z > 0) {

            console.log(' + - +');

            var rotateX = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 100).normalize().angleTo(new THREE.Vector3(crossVectors.x, 0, crossVectors.z).normalize());

            this.mesh.geometry.rotateY(-rotateX);

        } else if (crossVectors.x < 0 && crossVectors.y < 0 && crossVectors.z > 0) {

            console.log('- - +');

            var rotateX = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 100).normalize().angleTo(new THREE.Vector3(0, crossVectors.y, crossVectors.z).normalize());

            this.mesh.geometry.rotateX(-rotateX);

        } else if (crossVectors.x < 0 && crossVectors.y < 0 && crossVectors.z < 0) {

            console.log('- - -');

            var rotateX = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -100).normalize().angleTo(new THREE.Vector3(0, crossVectors.y, crossVectors.z).normalize());

            this.mesh.geometry.rotateX(rotateX);

        } else if (crossVectors.x > 0 && crossVectors.y > 0 && crossVectors.z > 0) {

            console.log('+ + +');

            var rotateX = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 100).normalize().angleTo(new THREE.Vector3(0, crossVectors.y, crossVectors.z).normalize());

            this.mesh.geometry.rotateX(rotateX);

        } else if (crossVectors.x < 0 && crossVectors.y > 0 && crossVectors.z < 0) {

            console.log('- + -');

            var rotateX = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 100).normalize().angleTo(new THREE.Vector3(0, crossVectors.y, crossVectors.z).normalize());

            this.mesh.geometry.rotateX(rotateX);

        } else if (crossVectors.x < 0 && crossVectors.y > 0 && crossVectors.z > 0) {

            console.log('- + +');

            var rotateX = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 100).normalize().angleTo(new THREE.Vector3(0, crossVectors.y, crossVectors.z).normalize());

            this.mesh.geometry.rotateX(rotateX);

        }

        else {

            alert('IMPOSSIBLE TO ALIGN');

        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

And the last step align the 2 and 3 point, calculating the angle beween.

I there any solution for that?

Really thanks guys, i'm getting a little crazy, i'm new on that.

I would like to have a simpler code for that, i'm 90% sure it exists a better way to do that.

The idea is to have the object on the plane aligned by the 3 points:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desired result, as you can see the foot is aligned with the floor plane.
[image]

Really thanks!

Comment: Are we talking about adjusting it to the horizontal plane (defined as (0,0,0) point and (0,0,1) vector) or about adjusting it to any plane?

Comment: Hi, we are talking about adjusting it ar (0,0,0) and (0,0,1). Actually i’m doing it by rotatingX and rotatingY, but it takes so many steps and ifs, i’m sure it exists better solution. It’s important to modify directly geometry. Thanks

Comment: Hint: something like `quat.setFromUnitVectors( crossVectors, planeNormal ); matrix.makeRotationFromQuaternion( quat ); geometry.applyMatrix4( matrix );`

Comment: Yes finally the quat works! THanks @WestLangley !! I tried other times without success but this time works! thanks.

 const quat = new THREE.Quaternion();
        quat.setFromUnitVectors( crossVectors.normalize(), new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1).normalize() ); 
        var mx4 = new THREE.Matrix4()
        mx4.makeRotationFromQuaternion( quat ); 
        this.mesh.geometry.applyMatrix4( mx4 );

Comment: Can you add a response to mark as solved and solution please?

Comment: That's OK, you can answer your own question and provide a complete explanation. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this with the response of @WestLangley, really thanks for your help.

There is the code to align the mesh to match the plane:

```
let subvector1, subvector2, crossVectors = new THREE.Vector3();

// Create the cross vector with the 3 points
subvector1.subVectors(this.aligningPoints[0], this.aligningPoints[2]);
subvector2.subVectors(this.aligningPoints[0], this.aligningPoints[1]);
crossVectors.crossVectors(subvector1, subvector2);

// Move the mesh (0,0,0) plane
this.mesh.geometry.applyMatrix4(new Matrix4().makeTranslation(-this.aligningPoints[0].x, -this.aligningPoints[0].y, -this.aligningPoints[0].z))

// Align the mesh to the plane with quaternion and matrix4
const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternion.setFromUnitVectors( crossVectors.normalize(), new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1).normalize() ); 
let matrix4 = new THREE.Matrix4()
matrix4.makeRotationFromQuaternion( quaternion ); 
this.mesh.geometry.applyMatrix4( matrix4 );
```